# sprite kit scene + tab bar controller

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, sprite-kit

I am really new to iOS programming, so any help is appreciated.

I am making a simple game. What I want is:

- a sprite kit welcome scene, which opens up(an animation) to the main game.
- the main game has 3 tabs, so I need a tab bar (like the one on the view controllers).
- two of those tabs will contain at least one sprite kit scene for the game play.

Right now, I have the animated welcome scene done, which opens up and go into the game scene when the user presses the screen, but there's no tabs(tab bar) on the main game scene.

What I don't know is that how should I do so that the scenes are linking together and also be able to shift/change and go between them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make and customize three view controllers and add SKView in each of them to show three different scenes. Use UITabbarController to handle this default way.

Comment: I got that figured out after writing a couple of small apps/programs. Thanks~